# Creating multiple templates with css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

What I'm trying to do is creating multiple boxes or templates (5 on each row) from a movie api, I currently can show all the data that I need (no need to be a responsive design).

[image: 1]

The problem is if I add my css class to my section "`<section id="raiz"></section>`" it just creates a box ands its overwritten by everything inside the ajax function. Here is the Code:

```js
var $peliculas = $.ajax({
  url: "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows",
  dataType: "json",
  method: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //raiz
      var root = document.getElementById("raiz");
      //Elements
      var Hipertexto = document.createElement("Hipertexto");
      var h1 = document.createElement("img");
      var puntuacion = document.createElement("puntuacion");
      var titulo = document.createElement("titulo");
      var generos = document.createElement("generos");
      Hipertexto.href = data[i].url;
      h1.src = data[i].image.medium;
      puntuacion.innerHTML = data[i].rating.average;
      titulo.innerHTML = data[i].name;
      generos.innerHTML = data[i].genres;
      raiz.appendChild(titulo);
      raiz.appendChild(generos);
      Hipertexto.appendChild(h1);
      raiz.appendChild(Hipertexto);
      raiz.appendChild(puntuacion);
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error");
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lavender;
  border: solid 1px silver;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section id="raiz"></section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Anybody have a suggestion what to do?

Comment: Your code has a bunch of problems.. First you are creating your own HTML tags. When you use the method `createElement` is to create valid HTML elements like `p` or `div`... you can't just create whatever elements as this is html and not xml.  Second... you don't need to use `createElement` as you are using jQuery, hence, use jQuery selectors. You code is pretty much invalid

Comment: what kind of jQuery selectors?

Comment: Please, check my answer and if you have any questions I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bunch of problems.. First you are creating your own HTML tags. When you use the method createElement is to create valid HTML elements like p or div... you can't just create whatever elements as this is html and not xml. Second... you don't need to use createElement as you are using jQuery, hence, use jQuery selectors. You code is pretty much invalid.

You can try something likes this... (this code is not perfect but shows how to use jQuery to append elements in the DOM)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows",
  dataType: "json",
  method: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // turn the array result into string
      var genre = data[i].genres.join(", ");
      
      //eq helps you to pinpoint the exact li element you are creating inside the li array
      $("#raiz ul").append('<li class="box"></li>');
      $("li").eq(i).append('<img src="' + data[i].image.medium + '"/>')
                    .append('<h2>' + data[i].name +'</h2>')
                    .append('<p>' + genre +'</p>')
                    .append('<p> Rating: ' + data[i].rating.average +'</p>');


    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error");
  }

});
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: lavender;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width:100%
  height: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <section id="raiz">
            <ul>
                
            </ul>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
```

Comment: Pretty much worked as intended, just added some minor tweaks, genres is actually already an array, so I didnt need the line "var genre = data[i].genres.join(", ");"
Thank you very much.